# jQuery: fire keyup on all document excluding one input text field

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, keyup, jquery-1.9

I have a

```
$(document).keyup(function(e) {
  //some code is here
});
```

code, that works as expected: it fires when I press any key on the keyboard.
I want it to fire, but not when the cursor is in the

```
<input type="text" id="excludeMeFromFiring">
```

which is on the page.

How to modify the code above to exclude firing when typing in the input text field with a special id? So it doesn't fire if the cursor is in the input text field.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's easy to do that in the `keyup` function:

```
$(document).keyup(function(e) {
    if ($(e.target).closest("#excludeMeFromFiring")[0]) {
        return;
    }

    // It's not that element, handle it
});
```

That's the general case; because `input` elements can't have any elements within them, you could just use `e.target.id` rather than `closest`:

```
$(document).keyup(function(e) {
    if (e.target.id === "excludeMeFromFiring") {
        return;
    }

    // It's not that element, handle it
});
```

I use `closest` whenever the element can have other elements inside it.

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
$(document).keyup(function (e) {
    if(e.target.id === 'excludeMeFromFiring'){
        console.log('no');
    }else{
        console.log('hi');
    }
});
```

---

```
$(document).keyup(function (e) {
    if(e.target.id !== 'excludeMeFromFiring'){
       console.log('hi');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Another Example:

```
$('#excludeMeFromFiring').keyup(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```